# Extending existing type testing.T for adding extra checks

Tags: testing, go

I realize I could pass the `testing.T` type to the functions that need to deal with the testing interfaces. But how about extending the struct and using it? I know I can type extend but this doesn't work unfortunately:

```
package test

import "testing"

type testingT testing.T

func (t *testingT) assert(val int) {
    if val == 0 {
        t.Errorf("%d is zero", val)
    }
}

func TestSomething(t *testingT) {
    t.assert(0)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is embedding as you can see in eduncan911's answer. It's great if you want to add other fields to the new struct.

However, this is not a requirement. Creating a new type having [`testing.T`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#T) as its underlying type (just as you did) is just enough:

```
type myT testing.T

func (t *myT) assert(val int) {
    if val == 0 {
        t.Errorf("%d is zero", val)
    }
}
```

#### Using it

In `TestSomething()` we can't just call `t.assert(0)` because `assert()` is not a method of `testing.T` but our `myT` type. So we need a value of type `myT` on which we can call `myT.assert()`.

We can't use [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to convert a `testing.T` to our `myT` type though, because type assertion requires the expression to be of interface type! And `t` is not an interface type, it's a concrete type: `*testing.T`.

The solution is really simple, we can use simple [type conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) because `myT` and `testing.T` has the same underlying type:

```
my := myT(*t)   // Conversion valid, but not yet enough, read on...
```

The above works, and we can call:

```
my.assert(0)
```

But when running tests, it **won't fail**! Why is that? It's because the above `*t` dereferencing, conversion and assignment will make a **copy**, and `my` will be of type `myT` but will be a copy of `*t`, and so when we call `myT.assert()`, it gets a pointer, but a pointer to the copy. And when `myT.assert()` calls `t.Errorf()`, it will register the error on a copy, so the testing framework will not see this `Errorf()` call.

The "final" solution is simple: use type conversion, but don't convert `*t`, but `t` itself (which is a pointer). Of course `*t` cannot be converted to `myT`, only to `*myT`. And this type needs to be parenthesized (to avoid ambiguity):

```
func TestSomething(t *testing.T) {
    my := (*myT)(t)
    my.assert(0)
}
```

And now we're happy, everything works as expected.

**Note:** You can also call `myT.assert()` in one line if you don't want to call multiple methods of `myT`:

```
func TestSomething(t *testing.T) {
    (*myT)(t).assert(0)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *embedding* which would allow you to add your owner methods:

```
package test

import "testing"

type testingT struct {
    *testing.T
}

func (t *testingT) assert(val int) {
    if val == 0 {
        t.Errorf("%d is zero", val)
    }
}

func TestSomething(t *testing.T) {
    t2 := &testingT{t}
    t2.assert(0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prepare custom testing struct:

```golang
type T testing.T

func (t *T) AssertEqualsInt(expected, actual int) {
    if actual != expected {
        // Correct point for file and line where happened error
        t.Helper()
        t.Errorf("Values not equal expected: %d, got: %d", expected, actual)
    }
}

func (t *T) AssertEqualsString(expected, actual string) {
    if actual != expected {
        t.Helper()
        t.Errorf("Values not equal expected: %s, got: %s", expected, actual)
    }
}
```

Than use it in testing:

```golang
func TestFooBarBaz(t *testing.T) {
    (*T)(t).AssertEqualsInt(0, 10)
    (*T)(t).AssertEqualsString("foo", "bar")
}
```